# How to use emacsclient on root files, using sudo and a single daemon

Tags: emacs, permissions, emacsclient

I always run emacs as daemon but when I want to make something alike

```
sudo emacsclient /etc/make.conf
```

I can't do it because root is using another emacs and I don't really want to run 2 daemons or wait usual emacs load for simple file.

I need some solution alike `emacsclientsudo /etc/make.conf` :) to edit system files with user emacs client.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

add to your `~/.profile`:

```
alias E="SUDO_EDITOR=\"emacsclient\" sudo -e"
```

then

```
E /etc/hosts
```

You should be able to use `sudoedit` instead of `sudo -e`, but I couldn't find
the former on my Mac.

Comment: Neat. I think you can just set SUDO_EDITOR in your init scripts and directly call `sudo -e` or `sudoedit` on whatever file you want though.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure about it directly but here's a trick

```
emacsclient -e '(find-file "/sudo::/etc/passwd")'
```

Uses tramp and the sudo method to open `/etc/passwd` as root.

You can alias this and use it directly from your shell.

Comment: The question is not clear, whether Emacs server runs as root or not. The other answer assumes that the server runs as root. Your answer assumes that the server runs unprivileged.

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Spacemacs ... sudo -e does, though.

Comment: How to wait for `Ctrl-x` `#`?